How can I extract data line from a grid chart?
Within the scope of my graduation project, I need to digitise chart data such as temperature, pressure, rain informations kept in charts. They each have certain chart and certain template. My problem is that detecting the data line from the grid lines.
An example image can be found here.(Since I don't have enough reputation I cannot share image directly, sorry :( ) Having curvy horizontal lines is also creates problems.
We tried to find the data line by using contour methods. However, we generally acquired irrelevant lines due to noise created by freqeunt grid lines. We tried to find the line by color difference but we have so many old images and some are black and white.

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is very broad. This is not how SO works. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem. If you have many problems you should address each with a seperate question. Please start coding a first step and share a minimal reproducible example so that others can work on it.

What is your requirements for data extraction, do you need to re-create the whole graph or do you need some statistical measurements like min max average or sampled points throughout the graph. Also can you share a black-white  graph too.

We need to convert the data line to excel table in values for hours. Therefore I need to extract the all data line.
